# How to control dynamically generated iframe width in ipad vesion safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

While using bootstrap 3 grids to control the width of dynamically generating iframe, unable to fit in the particular width, by default it is generating width 2890 which I am not able to control in mentioned grid width, particularly in iPad/iPhone safari and chrome browser.

Please help.

Comment: Add a minimal code example.

Comment: you have to add **object-fit: cover;** or else **overflow: hidden;** property.